# excel -how do you change the row order of data in a column into different row positions based upon 1 cell criteria in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Edited question to hopefully make clearer.

I have a worksheet which uses formula to import data (Football results) from another worksheet,within the workbook, which show's column data in a specific row order.

Column a / row 1 - a1 - is a specific football team name

column b - row 1 informs if the game is H or A - Home or away (this is determined if a1 matches either b2 or b5) 
b2 - shows away team name
b3 - shows the home team result
b4 - shows the away team result
b5 - shows home team name

I want to show in b6 the result of the team named in a1 - irrespective of it being H or A game, and then in b7 the result of the opposing team - again irrespective of it being a H or A game - keeping the data in b1 to b5 unchanged.This would then be applied to subsequent games played in adjacent columns.
Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Too hypothetical.  Please give an example.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yes is true that you have not  presented the questions properly. Better share some sample data & the expected output, will help us to fix the issue. ☺

Comment: is there a formula here : "Home or away (this is determined if a1 matches either b2 or b5) " ? a sample data/file will help to clarify..